# Contact form submissions into Podio

Tags: wordpress, crm, submission, contact-form-7, podio

I am working with a Wordpress-website with different kinds of contact forms (Contact Form 7) which generates alot of different enquiries. Today these submissions is just sent via mail to everyone working at the company. Sometimes a potential lead is not contacted.

I am looking for a solution that gathers all submission into one place, labels them and offer the possiblity to write a comment.

My idea is to send all submissions to Podio. I have not used Podio myself, but it seems easy and you can generate "Tasks" by sending a mail to a specific Workspace-mailadress.
Described here: https://help.podio.com/hc/en-us/articles/201019558-Overview-of-tasks

But it seems like it's not possible to set a specific label direcly when you generate a Task via mail. I would like the label "Unanswered" to be set by default, or something.

Does Podio offer any apps or anything that does what I want, but better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podio can do what you want:

1. You can use Podio to create a webform dedicated to a particular 'app' that you design. When you set up the 'app' you can specify a 'category' type field which can have "Unanswered" as a default value.
2. If you don't want to use the Podio webforms, then, as you say, you can add a record to an app via email. In this case, you should also create a Podio 'workflow' which will allow you to trigger events such as creating a new record in an app and setting a value, say to "Unanswered".

I strongly suggest you sign up to Podio (free initially) and experiement with the above methods. The Podio documentation will give you more information on 'webforms', 'emailing apps' and 'workflows'.

Anyway, this should point you in the right direction.